# How to select "input type" value dinamically created through JS

Tags: javascript, input

When i got an HTML page which has a form like this

```
<form name='form'>
<label>Title <input id = "larger_title" type='text' maxlenght="100" name='ticket_title' value=''></label>
```

i select its value by using

```
    const form=document.forms['form'];
    form.addEventListener('submit',create);
     ... 
    form.ticket_title.value
```

But when i do create an input type element through JS, so dinamically, for example as if i have an array of elements, each of them with a button that enables a function where are sent data that includes these input text, how do i select the values of these like i used to with form, but now without a form, straight from js itself?

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.name="post_solution";
    input.value="";
```

This code is outside the function related to the button, but how do i select its values in the function?
How should i select the text inserted in the input area whenever the user submits the button?

Comment: You can use `form['post_solution'].value` for instance. You can also use `const fd = new FormData(form);` and use its methods to access the form contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interacting with a dynamically created element is no different than interacting with a static one - - you access its properties and methods the same way.

Your problem is that although your code to create a new dynamic element isn't actually inserting the element into the document, so although it exists, it can't be found in the DOM. It should be appended to the document first:

```js
const form=document.forms['form'];
form.addEventListener('submit',create);

function create(event){
  form.ticket_title.value;
  form.post_solution.value = "TEST";
}

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.name="post_solution";
input.value="";

// Now, insert the element into the document
document.querySelector("form >  div").appendChild(input);
```

```html
<form name='form'>
  <div>
    <label>Title <input id = "larger_title" type='text' maxlenght="100" name='ticket_title' value=''></label>
  </div>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

But, accessing your `form` fields through the use of `document.forms[]` is quite ancient and really should be retired and instead use the modern [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead. `.querySelector()` accepts any valid CSS selector as a way of locating the first matching elment.

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit',create);

function create(event){
  form.ticket_title.value;
  form.post_solution.value = "TEST";
}

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.name="post_solution";
input.value="";

// Now, insert the element into the document
document.querySelector("form >  div").appendChild(input);
```

```html
<form name='form'>
  <div>
    <label>Title <input id = "larger_title" type='text' maxlenght="100" name='ticket_title' value=''></label>
  </div>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! 
the " document.querySelector("form >  div").appendChild(input); " only works if i have a form already in the html, right? And given that i have several tickets, the append is going to have effect for every ticket right? so i will have like one form with x post_solution inside?

Or do i need to create a single new one form for each of the x tickets?

Comment: I have fixed the append part, with a generic form inside the div where i create all the tickets. So after the createElement input/textarea i do an append for those tickets who need to and i got more than one post_solution and post_solved_by inside the generic form : i think this may be a problem, because when i try (inside the button related handler function) to get those form values i got "undefined".

Comment: @Redbite To your first comment above, any kind of querying for an element will only work if the element is already part of the document. You will have to append each and every dynamically created element to the document - - you can't just do one append for multiple elements.

Comment: @Redbite As for your second comment, you really should post a new question and include all the relevant code that you have now with your current question because it's hard to understand what your current issue is based on the code you've posted here.

Comment: In the end i have opted for a modal view, thanks for the answer - it was still a valuable lesson that could end up be useful in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

First you add an id or class property to the input:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.name="post_solution";
input.id = "myInput";
input.value="";
```

Then you use `document.getElementById`:

```
const input = document.getElementById('myInput');
input.addEventListener('onchange', handleChange);
```

Comment: It is not necessary to add an `id` or a class to an element to be able to find it later.

Comment: Would this work, if i have more than one created element in the same page? They would all have the same id.